# Previous loop won't show after new loop is made

Tags: java, loops

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Life {

static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[][] world;
    world = new String[20][20];
    String alivecell = "A";
    String deadcell = "D";
    int day = 0;

    for (int a = 0; a < 20; a++) {
        for (int a2 = 0; a2 < 20; a2++) {
            world[a][a2] = deadcell;
            //shows every cell as dead 
        }
    }
    int more = 1;

    do {
        int c = 0;
        int r = 0;
        int cr = 2021;

        // starts out with column and row together as a whole number
        while (cr > 2020) {
            System.out.println("Which column and row do you want a cell to be on ?");
            System.out.println("(the max number for column and row is 20 x 20 but starts at 0 )");
            cr = input.nextInt();

            if (cr > 1000) {
                c = cr / 100;// breaks into 2 (as column and row separate)
                r = cr % 100;
            } else {
                c = cr / 10;
                r = cr % 10;
            }
        }

        day = 1;/// a day of living cell(s) has begun and wont change until user prompts to start game
        System.out.println("day " + day);
        for (int a = 0; a < 20; a++) {
            for (int a2 = 0; a2 < 20; a2++) {
                world[a][a2] = deadcell;// which cells are still dead
                world[c][r] = alivecell;// WHICH CELLS SHOULD BE ALIVE
                System.out.format("%3s", world[a][a2]);
            }

            System.out.println();

        }

        System.out.println("add more living cells (type 1) or start game (press any other button)?");

        more = input.nextInt();

    } while (more == 1);

}

}
```

The output:

> Which column and row do you want a cell to be on ?
>
> (the max number for column and row is 20 x 20 but starts at 0 )
>
> 00
>
> day 1
>
> A D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D
>   D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D
>   D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D
>   D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D
>   D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D
>   D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D
>   D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D
>   D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D
>   D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D
>   D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D
>   D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D
>   D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D
>   D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D
>   D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D
>   D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D
>   D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D
>   D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D
>   D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D
>   D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D
>   D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D
>
> add more living cells (type 1) or start game (press any other button)?
>
> 1
>
> Which column and row do you want a cell to be on ?
>
> (the max number for column and row is 20 x 20 but starts at 0 )
>
> 01
>
> day 1
>
> D A D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D
>   D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D
>   D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D
>   D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D
>   D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D
>   D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D
>   D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D
>   D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D
>   D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D
>   D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D
>   D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D
>   D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D
>   D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D
>   D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D
>   D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D
>   D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D
>   D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D
>   D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D
>   D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D
>   D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D D
>
> add more living cells (type 1) or start game (press any other button)?

What I am trying to do:

What I was trying to was to make some cells (by prompting user) to be living (A) but when I try to make more cells but instead of adding more living onto the grid it instead moves the living cell to a different area.

When first loop showed ADD.... (alivecell, deadcell, deadcell) but when second loop was done, instead of showing AADD.... (after user prompts to add another living cell onto the grid) it outputs with DADDDD.... (the first loop isn't showing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your nested `for` loops are setting everything except the cell at `[r][c]` to be dead, every time the user specifies where a live cell should be.

You should initialize all of the cells to dead *before* the `while` loop, and just use it to make the cells the user specifies alive.

Answer (score 0):

No need of `for` loops again.

Only needed `world[c][r] = alivecell;` statement without for loop.

```
 //   System.out.println("day " + day);
  //          for (int a = 0; a < 20; a++) {
 //               for (int a2 = 0; a2 < 20; a2++) {
  //                  world[a][a2] = deadcell;// which cells are still dead
                    world[c][r] = alivecell;// WHICH CELLS SHOULD BE ALIVE
  //                  System.out.format("%3s", world[a][a2]);
  //              }

   //             System.out.println();

   //         }
```